# Extend a lighthouse directive

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

I want to extend a directive @modelClass from the lighthouse library.
I'm working on a modular architecture and I don't have an Eloquent Model, I have several, and I'm extending my first Model version, that's why I'm using an interface to bind the last Model that I need. 
What I need to do it is to use an interface instead a model class to resolve my type object.

Using the directive @modelClass should looks like this:

```
type User @modelClass(class: "App\\Models\\versionC\\User") {
  id: Int!
  username: String!
}
```

Since I have this binding:

```php
$this->app->bind(UserInterface::class, User::class)
```

I should have something like:

```
type User @modelClass(interface: "App\\Interfaces\\UserInterface") {
  id: Int!
  username: String!
}
```

But I cannot override or extend the @modelClass directive.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found it was manipulate the schema

```
type User @entity(interface: "App\\Interfaces\\UserInterface") {
  id: Int!
  username: String!
}
```

```php
class EntityDirective extends BaseDirective implements TypeManipulator
{
    public static function definition(): string
    {
        return /** @lang GraphQL */ <<<'SDL'
"""
Map an interface model class to an object type.
This can be used when an eloquent model it is bind to an interface.
"""
directive @entity(
    """
    The interface class name of the corresponding model binding.
    """
    interface: String!
) on OBJECT
SDL;
    }

    public function manipulateTypeDefinition(DocumentAST &$documentAST, TypeDefinitionNode &$objectType)
    {
        $modelClass = $this->directiveArgValue('interface');
        if(!$modelClass) {
            throw new DefinitionException(
                "An `interface` argument must be assigned to the '{$this->name()}'directive on '{$this->nodeName()}"
            );
        }

        $modelClass = get_class(resolve($modelClass));
        // If the type already exists, we use that instead
        if (isset($documentAST->types[$objectType->name->value])) {
            $objectType = $documentAST->types[$objectType->name->value];
        }

        $objectType->directives = ASTHelper::mergeNodeList(
            $objectType->directives,
            [PartialParser::directive('@modelClass(class: "'.addslashes($modelClass).'")')]
        );

        $documentAST->setTypeDefinition($objectType);
    }
}
```

*for the record I'm using lighthouse v4.10*